# How to disable geo loadbalancing in Google Cloud Load Balancer (non-Classic) HTTPS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-http-load-balancer

We are using GCP load balancer non-Classic HTTPS.  We have two instance groups, one in Central and one in East.  Right now it is sending all incoming traffic to only the nearest instance group.  We actually want to turn off geo loadbalancing and just round-robbin the traffic across ALL instance groups.

How do we actually do that?  This is not obvious from UI and documentation

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this?  While the Global LB prefers to route to the closest region to the client, it will also route to the next (nearest) region if there is no capacity in the nearest region.   Have a look at https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#target-capacity

Comment: @GariSingh Yeah this is basic.  Azure Front Door, for example, can do this.  This is yet another example of a non-obvious limitation in GCP that matters

Comment: Could you point me to how you'd do this with Azure Front Door?  I don't see how you'd do this there either.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround available for this issue. You need to recreate a new load balancer for your instance group and need to reconfigure it with your desired functionalities (round robin algorithm in your case). However if you are trying to edit your existing load balancer’s config as of now there is no way, there is a similar [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261517998) and a feature request has been raised with google team for it for more updates.

Comment: Thanks - I am happy to create a new one.  Which screen do I select "Round Robin" in?  I tried searching around and didn't see it in the create flow but maybe I just missed it

Comment: In GCP each type of load balancer by default supports a particular algorithm for more information go through [load balancing methods](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/features#load_balancing_methods) documentation.

Comment: Thanks - OK I am looking at the screen for a new HTTPS Load Balancer Backend Configuration.  There is a setting in Advanced called "Locality load balancing policy*".  The default choice is Round Robin.  However, there is no choice to NOT do locality load balancing at all and just do a pure Round Robin.  Am I missing something?  They all seem to be Locality Aware?  I think this just sets what to use within a locality, but I want to configure how it decides which locality.

Comment: If you are okay with using multiple load balancers, you can create an external load balancer and redirect the traffic to a regional LB for performing your round robin operations.

Comment: Thanks - wouldn't that still geo-route to the closest region though?

Comment: No you can use path based routing like for "EU" specify one path and for "US"  specify one path eg: eu.example.com and us.example.com.

Comment: But I don't want to do that.  I just want it to round robin across all regions.  Btw Azure front door can do this - it's pretty standard.